# How to grant one particular user read access to a unix file

Tags: unix, chmod, chown

I want to give one particular user read access to a file on a unix machine. I am not root so I guess I can not do `chown`.

I tried searching for something that uses `chmod`, but there it looks like I can't specify a particular user, only a one-self, group, or all.

I guess this was asked before already, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when you want more fine-grained permissions in Linux, you should use Access Control Lists. The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) has a good guide on how to set it up.

Once set up, you can define more complex rules for modifying the access control policies for your mounted filesystem.

You can set these rules with commands that look like: `setfacl -m "u:johny:r-x" abc`.
This says "Give (user) Johny read and execute permissions to the file/directory specified by the path `abc`".

You would then also be able to see the permissions for a filesystem object using `getfacl`

```
root@testvm:/var/tmp# getfacl appdir/
# file: appdir/
# owner: root
# group: appgroup
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:testusers:r--
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

In this example you can see the default for any user/group which is not (in) the `testusers` group, can read, write, or execute the directory. But `testusers` can only read.

Comment: man unix sucks real bad, huh

Answer (score 1):

The traditional, Unix way is, as you suggest, to `chown` the file and set permissions that way.

You might also be able to use access control lists (ACLs). Have a look for the `getfacl` and `setfacl` commands ([link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/getfacl.htm)). The bad news is that [ACLs are not always enabled](https://bencane.com/2012/05/27/acl-using-access-control-lists-on-linux/) and the default OS install doesn't always include the commands, which doesn't help you if you don't have root.